# node v16 excessive baseline memory usage on arm64

Tags: node.js, docker, x86-64, arm64

I am concerned with the baseline memory usage of node v16.15.0 on arm64. I am inside a docker container on arm64 and get about 40MB total of baseline memory usage, specifically 30MB of rss, running `process.memoryUsage()` in interactive node (it's clean & 100% reproducible). Using the x86_64 equivalent, via `from --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.15.0-buster`, the rss is 0 and the sum of all memory stats is about 12MB, which is much less. Any explanation as to why a clean node process requires so much more memory on arm64? There is no code of my own involved, just official node images, as stated above.

Comment: An RSS of `0` doesn't sound plausible.  It must have some pages of memory; maybe whatever software is managing running x86-64 binaries on ARM64 is breaking the accounting of memory so RSS shows as 0 for that one.  Especially a JIT engine like in node.js will have some dynamically private dirty pages of memory that will definitely contribute to its own RSS, not just shared mappings of machine code from disk files like the executable or libraries.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I checked for the native x86_64 setting and indeed you are right, there the RSS is also ~40 MB, there must be something fishy going on with the reporting. However, I still consider 40 MBs quite a lot for an empty process, but maybe I need to rethink what **heavy** means these days

Comment: Yeah, I wonder where all that memory is going.  Hopefully some of it is just large allocations that it hasn't used much of yet, but which it initialized or something to get the pages faulted in to RAM.  Or some is part of a free list of memory that got used during startup but is now ready to be re-allocated.  But not handed back to the OS yet.  So if we're lucky, it won't need to allocate more RAM right away when it needs to JIT some code and make space for some variables.  But with a bunch of dynamically linked libraries and stuff, I'm not shocked Node would 40MB.